# Find if N! is divide by n^2

Tags: algorithm

I have got an exercise which requires to find to write a program in which you   should find if N! is divided by N^2.
 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^9
I wanted to this with the easy way of creating factorial function and dividing it to the power of N but obviously it won't work.
 Just algorithm or pseudo-code would be enough

Comment: Since this is a homework problem, can you tell us what you have tried so far and where specifically you're stuck?

Comment: Is `n` and `N` in your question the same number?

Comment: @JohnFeminella i mentioned trying to do with standard way of creating factorial function and dividing it to `pow(n,2)` but it it didn't work.Becuse N can be up to 1 billion

Comment: If calculating n! does not work you need another idea. Consider which prime factors you have in n!.

Comment: @Henry won't counting all the prime factors of 1 billion take some time too?

Comment: Not really, no. It would if you attempted it by brute force..

Comment: @Henry okay now i have prime factors,what do i do with them?

Comment: @PapaJoh compare with the prime factors of n.

Comment: `N^2` divides `N!` if and only if `N` is 1 or a composite number other than 4. The problem with `4` is that there are no multiples of `2` strictly between `2` and `4`. For any other prime power `p^k` (with `k > 1`) there will be multiples of `p` strictly between `p^(k-1)` and `p^k`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any `n > 4`, if `n` is a `prime`, then `n!` is not evenly divisible by `n^2`.

Here is simple explanation to support my argument:

After `n!` is divided by `n`, we are left with `(n-1)!` in the numerator that needs to be divided by `n`. So we need `n` or a multiple of `n` in the numerator in order for `(n-1)!` to be evenly divisible by `n`, which can never happen when `n` is prime.

While the above will always happen when `n` is a non-prime. Check it out for yourself by diving into a bit of **Number Theory**

Hope it helps!!!

**Edit:** Here is a simple Python code for the above. Complexity is `O(sqrt(N))`:

```
def checkPrime(n):
  i = 2
  while i<n**(1/2.0):
    if n%i == 0:
      return "Yes"  # non-prime, so it's divisible
    i = i + 1
  return "No"  # prime, so not divisible

def main():
  n = int(raw_input())
  if n==1:
    print "Yes"
  elif n==4:
    print "No"
  else:
    print checkPrime(n)

main()
```

**Input:**

```
7
```

**Output:**

```
No
```

Answer (score 1):

This is related to though easier than [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem) which says that a number `n > 1` is prime if and only if

```
(n-1)! = -1 (mod n)
```

This is algebraically equivalent to saying that `n>1` is prime if and only if

```
n! = -n (mod n^2)
```

Furthermore, it is known and easy to prove that (to quote the Wikipedia article)

> With the sole exception of 4, where 3! = 6 ≡ 2 (mod 4), if n is
>   composite then (n − 1)! is congruent to 0 (mod n).

Hence with the sole exception of 4, if `n` is composite, `(n-1)! = 0 (mod n)` hence `n! = 0 (mod n^2)` and if `n` is prime, `n! = -n = n^2-n (mod n^2)` hence `n!` isn't congruent to `0` in that case.

The full power of Wilson's theorem is needed if you want to show that for prime `n`, `n!` leaves a remainder of exactly `n^2-n` upon division by `n^2`. For this problem all you need to know is that it isn't zero.

In any event, you could just write a program which runs a primality check, although whether or not that would be considered a valid solution is up to whoever assigned the problem.